# Pass function parameter while subscribing to an event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using following jquery pubsub for custom events:

```
(function($) {

  var o = $({});

  $.subscribe = function() {
    o.on.apply(o, arguments);
  };

  $.unsubscribe = function() {
    o.off.apply(o, arguments);
  };

  $.publish = function() {
    o.trigger.apply(o, arguments);
  };

}(jQuery));
```

and I'm subscribing to an event like this:

```
 $.subscribe("VALIDATE_ADDRESS", this.validateAddress);
```

**Question:** How can I pass some data to `validateAddress` method while subscribing to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Us a function wrapper (which you probably should be doing anyway, for `this`):

```
var obj = this;
$.subscribe("SOMETHING", function() {
  obj.validateAddress(someData, someOtherData);
});
```